# How to change spvoice language

Tags: delphi, text-to-speech, region

Trying to make Russian language flashcards with pronounciation using Delphi 2010. I can make it work on English.  I have Russian installed as Text2Speech language on Win10, but I do not know how to switch the language.

This speaks: `SpVoice1.Speak('Hello, what's up', SVSFDefault);`
This is silent: `SpVoice1.Speak('Привет, как дела', SVSFDefault);`

Comment: Are you using the [`ISpVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee413476%28v%3dvs.85%29) interface in SAPI 5.4? If so, maybe you could try the [`SetVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee125021%28v%3dvs.85%29) method?

Answer (score 2):

Since this was hard to find, I reply to my own thread with what I found by dissecting someone else's code.  I put this in the `OnCreate` event to change the voice:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AllVoices: ISpeechObjectTokens;
begin
  AllVoices := SpVoice1.GetVoices('', '');
  SpVoice1.Voice := AllVoices.Item(2);
end;
```

It works, since on my machine the Russian voice happens to be 2, so obviously I still need to figure out how to make this work properly.  But it is a start...